# How to make "Hamburger Menu" using Xamarin + MVVMCross 4.2 on a project containing PCL + Android + iOS?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, hamburger-menu

I found 2 distinct projects (Android and iOS) that make a hamburger menu. These work separately and do not use mvvmcross.

Anybody knows how to make "hamburger menu" in a single Xamarin solution with 3 projects (Core, Android and iOS) with MVVMCross 4.2?

Comment: You can checkout [XPlatformMenus](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus) in the MvvmCross-Samples repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can checkout [XPlatformMenus](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus) in the [MvvmCross-Samples](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples) repo.

> Features
>
> - **Hamburger menu navigation on all platforms**
> - Platform agnostic services implemented in the Core
> - Platform specific services implemented in the platform projects
> - Registration of platform specific services during application start-up
> - Custom application start-up (Core.AppStart)
> - FluentLayout on iOS

In Android it is using [Xamarin.Android.Support.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/) `DrawerLayout` to create the menu.

In iOS it is using [MvvmCross.iOS.Support.JASidePanels](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.iOS.Support.JASidePanels/) for the `SidePanels`